# Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE for nonexistent channel 257

Tags: ssh, solaris-11, mobaxterm

I have the same problem with MobaXterm versions 21.x, 22.x and 23.x when connecting to one specific solaris 11.1 SPARC T4 server/LDOM/zone.

```
Authenticating with public key "Imported-Openssh-Key"
user@prjcode-role:~#
Received SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE for nonexistent channel 257
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Session stopped
    - Press <Return> to exit tab
    - Press R to restart session
    - Press S to save terminal output to file
If I press "R", the session [re]starts and displays normally.
```

Note: This is not a timeout or hostname resolution error.  Google did not turn up any hits that helped resolve the nonexistent channel issue or anything useful that is specific to MobaXterm.

I have compared /etc/profile, ~/.profile, and /etc/ssh/sshd_config across other zones in the same LDOM and found no differences between those that work and the one that does not. I have compared /etc/hosts (linked to /etc/inet/hosts), /etc/nsswitch.conf, /etc/resolv.conf and the SMF configs of all zones in the same LDOM.  I have also deleted my ssh client known_hosts and config files (in MobaXterm) to level the playing field with no success. There does not seem to be any difference using keyboard interactive passwords or ssh keys either.

Regardless of server OS version or SSH server/client application versions, MobaXterm can connect to all zones in the LDOM except one without error. The OS and ssh version/configuration is the same for all zones under the LDOM.

I am stumped.